# Transforming a time-series into a data frame and back

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

The output of a time-series looks like a data frame:

```
ts(rnorm(12*5, 17, 8), start=c(1981,1), frequency = 12)

       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul     ...
1981 14.064085 21.664250 14.800249 -5.773095 16.477470  1.129674 16.747669 ...
1982 23.973620 17.851890 21.387944 28.451552 24.177141 25.212271 19.123179 ...
1983 19.801210 11.523906  8.103132  9.382778  4.614325 21.751529  9.540851 ...
1984 15.394517 21.021790 23.115453 12.685093 -2.209352 28.318686 10.159940 ...
1985 20.708447 13.095117 32.815273  9.393895 19.551045 24.847337 18.703991 ...
```

It would be handy to transform it into a data frame with columns Jan, Feb, Mar... and rows 1981, 1982, ... and then back. What's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: i needed that to boxplot() the seasons, today I played with ggplot and it needs again another format, its not aware what you usually want from your data as the plot family did. I feel that one is always inprisoned by the current dataformat you use. the transformations feel clumsy or dirty, see Mr. Grothendieck mingeling with month.abb etc. Nobody thought at making a transformation  library yet? as.data.frame(ts), as.qplot(ts, geom="boxplot") etc..? Do others feel the same pain as I do?

Comment: boxplotting can be done using `boxplot(tt ~ cycle(tt))` where `tt` is your `"ts"` series.  The zoo package does have time series specific plotting.  See `?plot.zoo` and `?xyplot.zoo` in that package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here are two ways. The first way creates dimnames for the matrix about to be created and then strings out the data into a matrix, transposes it and  converts it to data frame. The second way creates a by list consisting of year and month variables and uses tapply on that later converting to data frame and adding names.

```
# create test data
set.seed(123)
tt <- ts(rnorm(12*5, 17, 8), start=c(1981,1), frequency = 12)
```

**1) matrix**.  This solution requires that we have whole consecutive years

```
dmn <- list(month.abb, unique(floor(time(tt))))
as.data.frame(t(matrix(tt, 12, dimnames = dmn)))
```

If we don't care about the nice names it is just `as.data.frame(t(matrix(tt, 12)))` .

We could replace the `dmn<-` line with the following simpler line using @thelatemail's comment:

```
dmn <- dimnames(.preformat.ts(tt))
```

**2) tapply**.  A more general solution using `tapply` is the following:

```
Month <-  factor(cycle(tt), levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
tapply(tt, list(year = floor(time(tt)), month = Month), c)
```

**Note:** To invert this suppose `X` is any of the solutions above. Then try:

```
ts(c(t(X)), start = 1981, freq = 12)
```

### Update

Improvement motivated by comments of @latemail below.

Comment: `data.frame(matrix(co2, ncol=frequency(co2), dimnames=dimnames(.preformat.ts(co2)) ))` for another attempt

Comment: Just an update comment following from a duplicate question - the second `tapply()` solution is preferable to the matrix if the `ts` doesn't fit the rectangle nicely - `tt <- ts(1:18, start=c(1,3), end=c(2,8), frequency=12)` for example will break it. The `tapply` also needs some ordering of the month abbreviations to make it match exactly - `tapply(tt, list(year = floor(time(tt)), month = factor(month.abb[cycle(tt)], levels=month.abb)), c)`

Answer (score 4):

**Example with the AirPassengers dataset:**

Make the data available and check its type:

```
data(AirPassengers)
class(AirPassengers)
```

Convert Time-Series into a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(AirPassengers, year = trunc(time(AirPassengers)), 
month = month.abb[cycle(AirPassengers)])
```

Redo the creation of the Time-Series object:

```
tsData = ts(df$AirPassengers, start = c(1949,1), end = c(1960,12), frequency = 12)
```

Plot the results to ensure correct execution:

```
components.ts = decompose(tsData)
plot(components.ts)
```

Comment: the only downside is that the variables within the data frame such as year are still a time series

Answer (score 2):

Try the package "tsbox"

`ts = ts(rnorm(12*5, 17, 8), start=c(1981,1), frequency = 12)
df = ts_df(ts)
str(df)`

`data.frame:    60 obs. of  2 variables:
time : Date, format: "1981-01-01" "1981-02-01" 
value: num  23.15 22.77 5.1 1.05 13.87`