# Convert ts object to data.frame and keep row- and colnames

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, time-series, data-conversion

I want to convert a [ts](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html) (i.e. timeseries) R object to a data.frame. The names of rows and columns of the ts object should be retained.

Consider the [AirPassengers](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/AirPassengers.html) data set:

```
data(AirPassengers)
```

I could convert this ts object to a data.frame as follows:

```
AirPassengers <- data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(AirPassengers), ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(AirPassengers) <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
rownames(AirPassengers) <- 1949:1960
```

However, this seems to be way too complicated. Surprisingly, a google search didn't show a simpler solution.

**Question: Is there a simple solution how to convert ts objects to a data.frame without losing colnames and rownames?**

Comment: Related [Transforming a time-series into a data frame and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331901/transforming-a-time-series-into-a-data-frame-and-back)

Comment: @PoGibas Thanks for the link! Indeed, I didn't find this thread myself and especially 2) of the accepted answer solves my problem in a more standardized way. However, I am very surprised that there seems to be no predefined R function.

Comment: If you are willing to use xts as timeseries solution you can "deconstruct" the timeseries. Use coredata(x) to deconstruct the data. Use index(x) to deconstruct the index/times. Deconstruct means you get out the data from xts into dataframe format.

Comment: @Toolbox The answer of Jozef perfectly fits my needs, so I'm going to use his approach. However, thanks a lot for your comment, good to know that there are further alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying issue is that the output of `print` for a time series object is quite heavily processed by `.preformat.ts`. If you want to convert it to a data frame that is visually similar to the print results this should do:

```
df <- data.frame(.preformat.ts(datasets::AirPassengers), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note that this will produce characters (as that is how `.preformat.ts` works), so be careful with the use (not sure what is the purpose of the conversion?).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!